# What's the best source-level debugger for ColdFusion MX 2004?

Tags: debugging, coldfusion

I have a legacy web site in ColdFusion MX 2004.  I'm re-writing it in .Net, so I don't want to pay $600+ for an upgrade to the latest version of ColdFusion, nor do I want to go through the (very large) site fixing version incompatibilities.

I often have to track down and fix bugs in the site.

A source-level debugger that would let me step through the code line-by-line and examine variables would be a HUGE time-saver.

Does anyone have experience using any of the third-party ColdFusion source-level debuggers?

Answer (score 8):

There's no such thing as ColdFusion MX 2004, neither in name nor release year (CFMX 6.1 was released in 2003, and CFMX 7 was released in 2005).

**[FusionDebug](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fd/)** supports all versions of CFMX from 6.1 onwards.

You may want to investigate **[BlueDragon.NET](http://www.newatlanta.com/bluedragon)**, which allows you to run CFML code on the .NET platform, and may make the transition easier for you.

Answer (score 3):

The [developer versions](http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads.html#proddownloads) of ColdFusion are free so you can install the latest version, install [debugging tools](http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads.html#cfdevtools) into eclipse and run debugging for free.

The other option, if you prefer to debug on your target version of CF, is [FusionDebug](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fd/) which supports CF 6.1 and up.

Comment: You should always develop the on the same version of CF as you have running on Live and Staging servers!

Answer (score 2):

There are certain debuggers listed here on Charlie Arehart's site.
http://www.carehart.org/cf411/#debug
This CF411 site has a whole lot of great info on various subjects.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have marked this question as answered. The answers are offered by others, but to be clear:

If you're running a version of CF prior to CF 8, then you can get line debugging using the available commercial third-party tool, FusionDebug (www.fusiondebug.com).

If you're running CF 8, it includes line debugging, for free.

Both approaches leverage the Eclipse IDE's built-in debugging capability, hooking it up to CF.

For more on each, I've written several articles:

[The ColdFusion 8 Debugger Explained: Interactive Step Debugging for CF 8](http://www.carehart.org/articles/#2008_4)

[Using the CF8 Debugger](http://www.carehart.org/articles/#2008_2)

[FusionDebug Explained: Interactive Step Debugging for CFML](http://www.carehart.org/articles/#2006_5)

[FusionDebug Tips and Tricks](http://www.carehart.org/articles/#2006_3)

Hope those help.

Answer (score 0):

BlueDragon.Net is interesting, but I installed it and found out that it does not do source-level debugging.